What are the reasons, that the 24.04 installer doesn't create sub-volumes, when using btrfs?
After about 15 years, I'm using Ubuntu again. The Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop Edition looks fine. Admittedly, I wanted to start with Fedora to some extent, but after a fresh installation, there are some sporadically bugged programs and the current kernel.
While Fedora is using btrfs as the default filesystem, I read some introductions to btrfs and am excited to use btrfs. Fedora (the installer) has created two sub-volumes "@" and "@home", but the Ubuntu Installer doesn't create any sub-volume or give the option for it?! What is the reason for it? Is this no longer best practice? If I understood correctly, past versions of the Installer have created the @ + @home subvolumes, that are also needed for timeshift?!
What is the best way to create the @ and @home subvolume after the installation on the existing Ubuntu system?

You mention Ubuntu, and a release (24.04) but not which product & thus installer you're talking about; Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server use different installers (ubuntu-desktop-installer & subiquity) with flavors using ubuntu-desktop-installer or calamares.  Ubuntu by default does not assume btrfs thus there maybe more involved than a different GNU/Linux that defaults to btrfs.

It is the 24.04 LTS Desktop Edition

The installer has been rewritten, I think, twice in the past decade or so, and in the meantime ZFS has become the shiny new thing for Canonical, and even that isn't well supported in this second rewrite yet. I'd guess btrfs isn't anywhere near the top of the priority list

if you are looking for a way to do it does this article help? As to your specific question about reasons - you would need to ask Canonical directly. Any comment here otherwise is surely just opinion based.

Thank you for that link to the article. I will have a look. Regarding the reasons, it could have been that something was reported about it. But it seems to be the case that the priority or focus is not currently on it.
